# VB.NET SqlCommand Connection not retrieving results, but only occasionally

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2012, sqlconnection

I'm having a weird issue with my code to retrieve results from an SQL database. The code is below, but the basics of it are as follows:

The connection get's opened, and then immediately executes the query. 8/10 times this works no problem, but sometimes inexplicably the query that get's executed will return no results, even though it's the exact same query to the same database that hasn't been modified. I've noticed that if I put in a threading.sleep function between the time the connection is opened, and the time it's closed, this issue goes away entirely, but for obvious reasons that's not ideal.

I've tried querying the status of the connection to see if it's ready, but it always reports that it's open, even if it's not getting any results from the DB.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    'Runs the passed query and returns each row as an object within an ArrayList
    Function Get_Results(ByVal query As String, ByVal ConnectionStringName As String) As ArrayList
        Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand = Get_Connection(query, ConnectionStringName)

        'Open that connection
        sqlComm.Connection.Open()

        'This part doesn't work because the connection will always report that it's open.
        While sqlComm.Connection.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While

        'pause and wait for the connection to fully open (maybe?)
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        'Execute the query and store all of the results into the SqlDataReader.
        Dim sqlRead As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        Dim result As ArrayList = New ArrayList

        'Read each row one by one.
        While sqlRead.Read()
            'Create an object of the size needed.
            Dim row(sqlRead.FieldCount - 1) As Object

            'Fill the row object with the values.
            sqlRead.GetValues(row)

            'Add the result object to the array.
            result.Add(row)
        End While

        'Close all open connections to the database.
        sqlRead.Close()
        sqlComm.Connection.Close()

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: My query has been completely irrelevant. I could try doing "SELECT 1 AS test" and it still won't work. I've even rewritten the code above to use a SqlDataSource and I'm still getting the same issue. So it's not likely an issue with the code, but instead the DB.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't have to wait for the connection to open or more precisely the `Open()` method won't return until the connection is really open (or it will time out).

Comment: You could start debugging this by checking the connection state property of the database connection (i.e. `Debug.WriteLine(sqlComm.Connection.State.ToString());`) . Put that right after your sqlComm.Open() - srry my VB is a little rusty. But just check the connection state of the connection before you try doing anything else. Post the code for you `Get_Connection` method, because if your connection is not open after that initial `sqlComm.Open()` then there might be server/hardware issues